# How Can I Keep My Tor Relay Stable When I Need To Do A Software Update

Tags: configuration, security, relays, fast-relays

I run a TOR relay under the name "torland" (http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/router_detail.php?FP=8d90596192e548c8c00fa9e82759f95b875dc99e). Just today, my relay became marked as a stable tor relay because  it has been running non-stop for around two weeks. However, my concern is: I'm going to need to shut my relay down eventually when my computer needs to do a software update, or if my internet connection is turned off for whatever reason. Is there a way I can keep my relay marked as stable when this happens? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting a relay will not cause it to lose it's *Stable* flag. *Stable* doesn't require 100% uptime, it requires that it be up *most* of the time, so restarting it to apply updates shouldn't cause it to lose it.

From [`dir-spec.txt`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n2424):

```
   "Stable" -- A router is 'Stable' if it is active, and either its Weighted
   MTBF is at least the median for known active routers or its Weighted MTBF
   corresponds to at least 7 days. Routers are never called Stable if they are
   running a version of Tor known to drop circuits stupidly.  (0.1.1.10-alpha
   through 0.1.1.16-rc are stupid this way.)

        To calculate weighted MTBF, compute the weighted mean of the lengths
        of all intervals when the router was observed to be up, weighting
        intervals by $\alpha^n$, where $n$ is the amount of time that has
        passed since the interval ended, and $\alpha$ is chosen so that
        measurements over approximately one month old no longer influence the
        weighted MTBF much.
```

This is by intent, since obviously relays *should* have some amount of downtime to do sensible things like install software updates.

Comment: Yes, this just happened and my relay is still marked as stable, thank you. What does being marked as Stable do for my relay? Thank you.

Comment: *Stable* simply means that the router is going to be available with high uptime, e.g. that it won't go down every day or similar. Tor uses them for *Long Lived Circuits*, e.g. circuits which use protocols that normally have long connection times like SSH, IRC or XMPP, unlike HTTP which often has quite short connection times. It's also a requirement for other flags allowing it to be used for other purposes like *Guard* or *HSDir* since they require that the relay have good uptime to work well.